# Why isn't this simple color change of a Font Awesome SVG icon not working?

Tags: html, svg, font-awesome

I'm trying to change the color of a Font Awesome icon. I'm **not using the font or the `<i>` markup**. I'm using a downloaded **.svg image file**.

The SVG inside the file is pretty simple:

```xml
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="cat" class="svg-inline--fa fa-cat fa-w-16"
  role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
  <path fill="currentColor" d="M290.59 192c-20.18 0-106.82 1.98-162.59 85.95V192c0-52.94-43.06-96-96-96-17.67 0-32 14.33-32 32s14.33 32 32 32c17.64 0 32 14.36 32
    32v256c0 35.3 28.7 64 64 64h176c8.84 0 16-7.16 16-16v-16c0-17.67-14.33-32-32-32h-32l128-96v144c0 8.84
    7.16 16 16 16h32c8.84 0 16-7.16 16-16V289.86c-10.29 2.67-20.89 4.54-32 4.54-61.81
    0-113.52-44.05-125.41-102.4zM448 96h-64l-64-64v134.4c0 53.02 42.98 96 96 96s96-42.98
    96-96V32l-64 64zm-72 80c-8.84 0-16-7.16-16-16s7.16-16 16-16 16 7.16 16 16-7.16 16-16
    16zm80 0c-8.84 0-16-7.16-16-16s7.16-16 16-16 16 7.16 16 16-7.16 16-16 16z"></path></svg>
```

I was expecting that the `fill="currentColor"` setting inside the .svg file would allow the image to change color with simple CSS styling, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Do SVG images *as files* always behave as if `currentColor` is black? Is there a way around this?

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://shetline.com/img/cat-solid.svg" width=50 height=50> ← SVG image defaults to black<br>
  <div style="color: red"><img src="https://shetline.com/img/cat-solid.svg" width=50 height=50> ← This SVG image should be red</div>
  <img style="color: blue" src="https://shetline.com/img/cat-solid.svg" width=50 height=50> ← This SVG image should be blue<br>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block; color: green; width: 50px; height: 50px;">
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="cat" class="svg-inline--fa fa-cat fa-w-16"
  role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
  <path fill="currentColor" d="M290.59 192c-20.18 0-106.82 1.98-162.59 85.95V192c0-52.94-43.06-96-96-96-17.67 0-32 14.33-32 32s14.33 32 32 32c17.64 0 32 14.36 32
32v256c0 35.3 28.7 64 64 64h176c8.84 0 16-7.16 16-16v-16c0-17.67-14.33-32-32-32h-32l128-96v144c0 8.84
7.16 16 16 16h32c8.84 0 16-7.16 16-16V289.86c-10.29 2.67-20.89 4.54-32 4.54-61.81
0-113.52-44.05-125.41-102.4zM448 96h-64l-64-64v134.4c0 53.02 42.98 96 96 96s96-42.98
96-96V32l-64 64zm-72 80c-8.84 0-16-7.16-16-16s7.16-16 16-16 16 7.16 16 16-7.16 16-16
16zm80 0c-8.84 0-16-7.16-16-16s7.16-16 16-16 16 7.16 16 16-7.16 16-16 16z"></path></svg></div>
← Applying color works when using inline SVG instead of SVG image file
```

Answer (score 2):

SVG files accessed as standalone external images (for instance `<img>` or `background-image`) have to be self-contained. Styling outside the file does not affect the SVG.

You can think of it as if it were just a PNG file.

Comment: It makes perfect sense *in general* that SVG files should be treated as self-contained entities. But `currentColor` seems like it should be a property specifically intended to bypass that isolation from external CSS styling. I guess, however, it sadly doesn't actually work that way.

Comment: It's for privacy reasons.  Being able to modify how an image is displayed could allow a malicious site to, for example, detect which sites you have visited.

Answer (score 1):

This is using FontAwesome 6.4.2 (pro, but that should not matter).

I found that setting `fill` to "none" on the svg tag and both the `stroke` and `fill` attributes to "currentColor" on the path tag allowed me to change the color freely with CSS. I do so with a class on the tag containing the SVG, not the SVG tag itself, though I'd imagine that would work as well.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
    <!--! Font Awesome Pro 6.4.2 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2023 Fonticons, Inc. -->
    <path stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" d="...path info..."/>
</svg>
```

Alternatively, you can use the CSS `filter` setting, but that's less convenient to use in my opinion.

Comment: Should also have added that this is just an additional tip that I feel adds to the information here. This still would not work with an external SVG file as far as I know.